# Why set position: relative without changing location?

Tags: html, css

I am learning css and I wonder why we set position: relative even we don't set the specific location, such as `left: 20px`, `top: 10px`. Below is a sample of css code.

```
#home #header {
    position: relative;
    width: 822px;
    height: 152px;
    margin: 0 19px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 822px;
    height: 152px;
    margin: 0 19px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(img/bg-content-wrap-top-int.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually one of these 3 reasons:

- To affect how elements are stacked (it changes when you position an element with or without specific `z-index`).  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index
- As Niklas Ringdahl mentioned, `position:absolute` elements inside will be relative to the parent if the parent is `position:relative`.  See http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
- To ensure some other property is applied as desired or fix a glitch (as a "hack").  This is done for several reasons related to IE.

Answer (score 2):

In most situations it is used to set the `0,0` position for any child element that is positioned `absolute` inside `#header`.

Normally, if you do this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="fos">hehe</div>
</div>
```

and you use this css:

```
#fos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

your `#fos` element will be positioned `10,10` from the **top left corner of the page**. However, if you put `position: relative;` on `#header`, `#fos` will be positioned `10,10` from **the top left corner of `#header`**.

This would also happen if `#header` had anything else than `position: static` (which is the default value for `position`), but normally `relative` is used because it keeps the element in the document flow. So when you set it, and don't set any specific location, it will stay as it is, but `0,0` position will be changed.

I created a simple [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgj3F/) for you.

(it is also used in some other cases as **@rhyaniwyn** descibed quite well, I just wanted to explain this one a bit longer, this is a very powerful technique)

Comment: Very much deserves the focus; I couldn't function without it!

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory, but it's good to do if child elements should be use `position:absolute` since their relative position will be calculated against the closest parent element with `position:relative`

Comment: Actually, it'll be calculated relative to the closest parent with a `position` of *anything* other than `static`.  Just happens that the other `position` values radically affect on the position of the element, whereas `relative` is much more benign.